# What are the consequences when setting enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials to false on weblogic server

Tags: java, authentication, spring-boot, weblogic

In my weblogic server I have application where is enabled basic authentication(`web.xml` and `weblogic.xml`). Now I am porting spring-boot application from tomcat to weblogic where was basic authentication too but on application tier. So when I port this it does not work and I need to set `enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials` to `false`. Now I expected that I should refactor my first application which run on same domain(it runs on virtual host) but it seems authentication is still working in this application . So what are the consequences when I set this options on production server ?

Answer (score 8):

### Where it effects?

> The `enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials` flag effects the entire
>   domain. So, it will work for both of your project.

The enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials flag is true by default, and WebLogic Server authentication is performed. If authentication fails, the request is rejected. WebLogic Server must therefore have knowledge of the user and password.

You may want to change the default behavior if you rely on an alternate authentication mechanism. For example, you might use a backend web service to authenticate the client, and WebLogic Server does not need to know about the user. With the default authentication enforcement enabled, the web service can do its own authentication, but only if WebLogic Server authentication first succeeds.

If you explicitly set the `enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials` flag to false, WebLogic Server does not perform authentication for HTTP BASIC authentication client requests for which access control was not enabled for the target resource.

### Resource Link:

1. [Understanding BASIC Authentication with Unsecured Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/security/thin_client.html#wp1057361)
2. [WebLogic bypass basic authentication](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_weblogic_bypass_basic_authentication.htm)

### What Oracle Says about enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials?

> Oracle WebLogic Server authentication is enabled by default. However,
>   this configuration prevents Oracle WebLogic Server from using
>   application managed authentication. You must disable Oracle WebLogic
>   Server authentication by setting the
>   enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials parameter to false.
>
> ### Procedure
>
> To disable Oracle WebLogic Server authentication:
>
> 1. In a text editor, open the `config.xml` file for the domain where you deployed IBM CMIS for Content Manager OnDemand. The `config.xml`
>      file is in the
>      Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/domain_name/config directory.
> 2. Locate the `<security-configuration>` element.
> 3. Add the following argument to the end of the  element:
>
>    `<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth
>      -credentials>`
> 4. Start or restart all of the servers in the domain.

### Resource Link:

1. [Disabling Oracle WebLogic Server authentication for IBM CMIS for
   Content Manager OnDemand](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEUEX_2.0.3/com.ibm.installingeuc.doc/eucde085.htm)

---

### UPDATE#1:

### Why it is made to false?

> Whether or not the system should allow requests with invalid Basic
>   Authentication credentials to access unsecure resources. 
>   (Interface=weblogic.management.configuration.SecurityConfigurationMBean
>   Attribute=getEnforceValidBasicAuthCredentials)

Actually, you need to do 2 things here.

1. Sometimes it is not enough to make it false.
2. So, you need to add the flag via WLST :

> ```
> connect('weblogicUser','weblogicPassword','t3://localhost:7001')
> edit()
> startEdit()
> cd('SecurityConfiguration/Your_Domain')
> set('EnforceValidBasicAuthCredentials','false')
> save()
> activate()
> ```

**N.B: (Do not forget to edit with your weblogicUser, weblogicPassword, weblogic url and your domain in the 'cd' command...). If you do this things successfully, then it will effect on your configuration file.**

### Resolution:

After restarting server, If you looked in the `config.xml` file, and another tag has been added. Now, `config.xml` file looks like that :

```
.........
    <enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
    <use-kss-for-demo>true</use-kss-for-demo>
</security-configuration>
............
```

But this `use-kss-for-demo` tag may depend on your weblogic configuration. So It is strongly suggested by [Val Bonn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3758289/val-bonn) to use the WSLT way to update this flag.

### Resource Link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39619242/2293534

---

### UPDATE#2:

**So, you want to know that what is the impact?**

By default WebLogic Server looks at the Authentication Header, and even if your code and app is set to allow anonymous access, if there’s any HTTP Authentication header, WebLogic fails to handle the requests and throws up a browser login dialog:

[image]

The Publisher web service by default uses authentication headers, so the Publisher authentication headers get sent to your portlet code.  Fortunately, the fix for this is pretty straight-forward and documented to set enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials to false.

### Resource Link:

1. http://blog.integryst.com/webcenter-interaction/2010/03/24/setting-config-xml-for-weblogic-in-oracles-jdeveloper/

Comment: thx man but you said nothing new to me I already know how I can change this setting with wlst command and I really dont want to edit some xml where I can make some error. But I want to know what happend with weblogic server. He is using some authentication too. (admin console) or jmx authentication which is using in my application too

Comment: still same offtopic. As I said I already know how to change it ! I am just curious about consequences

Comment: @hudi Please check UPDATE#2 portion. I have tried to give you the answer why it is necessary to make it false.