# Asking twice for username and password in HTTP Basic authentication on Weblogic 12.2.1 with OHS

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, weblogic

I've a simple Java-based web application deployed on Weblogic 12.2.1 using OHS. There is a simple JSP page with a servlet for uploading files.

index.jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Checklist Administration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Checklist Upload</h2> 
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Upload Checklist (XML)</legend>
            <form action="checklist_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="fileName">Select Checklist: </label>
                <input id="checklistFile" type="file" name="checklistFile" accept=".xml"/><br/>            
                <input id="checklistButton" type="submit" value="Upload" disabled />
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("checklistFile").addEventListener("change", function(){
        if (document.getElementById("checklistFile").files.length == 1) {
            document.getElementById("checklistButton").disabled = false;
        }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Access to this page should be granted with Basic HTTP authentication. The user and group are configured as Realm in Weblogic and in the web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ChecklistUploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.teamead.aimsl.wsproxy.checklist.ChecklistUploadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ChecklistUploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/checklist/checklist_upload</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Preclude access to GET</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Checklist Admin</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/checklist/index.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/checklist/checklist_upload</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/checklist/result.jsp</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMIN_ROLE</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Admin Area</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>ADMIN_ROLE</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

The weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd 
                        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
        <wls:url-pattern>/xsd/*</wls:url-pattern>
        <wls:url-pattern>/wsdl/*</wls:url-pattern>
    </wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </wls:container-descriptor>

    <wls:security-role-assignment>
        <wls:role-name>ADMIN_ROLE</wls:role-name>
        <wls:principal-name>admin</wls:principal-name>
    </wls:security-role-assignment>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

The behavior is very strange. When try to upload a file using the URL
http://server:7001/checklist/index.jsp
then I'm being asked for credentials and after providing them the JSP page is shown, but then when I click on the "Browse" button, select a file and click on the "Upload" button, then I'm being asked again for the username and password. After providing these everything works and even when not providing them, but pressing Esc, I receive the HTTP Error 401--Unauthorized, then I press F5 for reload and the file is successfully uploaded. Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: How many weblogic servers do you have behind your OHS ?

Comment: There is just one server, OHS is using configured to forward the request to this Weblogic server instance in mod_wl_ohs.conf:

<Location /server>
  SetHandler weblogic-handler
  WLProxySSL ON
  RequestHeader Set Proxy-user-dn "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e"
  WebLogicHost 127.0.0.1
  WebLogicPort 23842
  FileCaching OFF
  WLSocketTimeoutSecs 60
  WLIOTimeoutSecs 3660
 </Location>

Comment: Looking for similar issues, I see the enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials quite often, but I do not believe this is a resolution in your case when you don't manage the authentication on application level.

How many security realms have you configured and how many providers and what type are they?

Could you also add your weblogic.xml for the realm mapping?

Interesting similar posted issue (old, though): https://community.oracle.com/thread/788268

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've added the weblogic.xml, will have a look at this parameter. There is just one security realm and 2 providers: DefaultAuthenticator and DefaultIdentityAsserter. I think the issue must be somehow connected to the fact, that the servlet is called from the form action in the JSP, since we've a similar situation, when a simple HTML site is also protected by Basic HTTP Auth and there is a link to a servlet and works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I had almost the same situation.

You need to turn off the `enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials` flag in the `config.xml`. By default, this flag set to `true`, so you need to turn it off.

Be warned that this is a WebLogic Domain related global setting.

This can solve your issue.

**Materials:**

- [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/security/thin_client.html#wp1057361)
- [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397917/what-are-the-consequences-when-setting-enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials-to-f)

Hope that this can help people to save time.